# Monodroid issue with jar binding zubhium sdk

Tags: android, binding, jar, xamarin.android

Iam trying to bind a jar(zubhium sdk jar) file to my mono droid project. I have followed their guide on xamarins website and created a new binding project which I reference I my mono droid project. 
I am having some issues with package names. I get the following error:

```
Error   3    package com.zubhium.interfaces does not exist
        com.zubhium.interfaces.ZubhiumListener
    C:\Users\jbp\Desktop\ny\CmsApp.Droid\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\com\zubhium\interfaces\ZubhiumListenerImplementor.java  8   25  CmsApp.Droid



 from the genrated source:
package mono.com.zubhium.interfaces;        
public class ZubhiumListenerImplementor
            extends java.lang.Object
            implements
                mono.android.IGCUserPeer,
                com.zubhium.interfaces.ZubhiumListener
```

And that is because when the project is wrapped it automaticly adds mono(.com.zubhium....) to the package name. I cant find how to remove this mono or if i can set a rule to add this part.

I tried to put  `<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.zubhium.interfaces']" name="managedName">mono.com.zubhium.interfaces</attr>`
in the xmldata.xml file but that did not work.

Do you guys have any sugestions?

Regards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
package com.zubhium.interfaces does not exist
```

When you [bind a `.jar` library](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/Binding_a_Java_Library_(.jar)) and [reference the binding project from another project](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/Binding_a_Java_Library_(.jar)#Using_the_Bound_Library), you need to *also* [add the `.jar` to your Application project](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/Binding_a_Java_Library_(.jar)#Add_the_Jar_to_the_Project) and set its **Build action** to `AndroidJavaLibrary`.

Failure to do so means that the `.jar` won't be added to the `javac` `$CLASSPATH`, resulting in `javac` compilation errors when compiling the [Android Callable Wrapper](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/architecture/android_callable_wrappers) (as you saw), and that the `.jar` won't included into your final `.apk`. Both of these are Bad™.

> And that is because when the project is wrapped it automaticly adds mono(.com.zubhium....) to the package name.

That's for an "Implementor" type; you can ignore it. It's used as part of the implementation of events. If you look at the generated C# code, there should be:

```
[global::Android.Runtime.Register ("mono/com/zubhium/interfaces/ZubhiumListenerImplementor")]
internal sealed class ZubhiumListenerImplementor : Java.Lang.Object, IZubhiumListener {
    // ...
}
```

The `mono.com.zubhium.interfaces.ZubhiumListenerImplementor` is the ACW for the internal `ZubhiumListenerImplementor` type.

You can't rename this type; it's an internal construct that isn't controlled via metadata.

Comment: Beautiful thank you very much now I got it to compile without errors. Do you have any pointers to how I now access any classes and methods contained in the jar file.

Comment: What problem are you having accessing the members? The output of a Java Binding Project is an assembly (`.dll`). When you add a project reference to the Java Binding Project, the assembly is added as an assembly reference, so you should be able to Just Use the types/methods within it, provided you use the right names.

Comment: Apparently I am having some issues with name spaces. But I have access to the methods. Thank you very much for the help.